# How can I get a custom field from Active Directory in C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've read plenty of similar StackOverflow questions but none seem to address the issue I'm seeing. If I query for a user using **userprincipalname** I get back a search result with exactly 34 properties. None of the custom properties are returned. If I query again using a custom property like **employeeNumber** I get back a result with 71 properties. All custom properties are included.

My issue is that I don't have the **employeeNumber** at run time, just the **userprincipalname**. I need to get back all of the custom properties all of the time. Hopefully that makes sense. Here's my practice code:

```
string sid = "";
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
    //sid = user.SamAccountName;
    sid = user.UserPrincipalName;
    //sid = user.Sid.ToString();

    DirectoryEntry entry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
    if (entry.Properties.Contains("employeeNumber"))
    {
        //this doesn't work
    }
}

DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("companyname.com");
ldapConnection.Path = "LDAP://DC=companyname,DC=com";
ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);
search.Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass=user)(userprincipalname={0}))", sid); // <-- this doesn't get custom properties
//search.Filter = string.Format("(employeeNumber={0})", "11663"); <-- this works

var result = search.FindOne(); // FindOne();
if (result.Properties.Contains("employeeNumber"))
{
    //this never happens either :(
}
```

The above never returns the **employeeNumber** field, but if I uncomment the second search.Filter line and manually search by **employeeNumber** I find a result and it contains all of the fields that I need.

EDIT: I found a very good MSDN article [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552835.aspx) which describes how to extend the UserPrincipal object to get custom attributes. The only issue is that it's giving me an empty string every time I access it even though I have verified that the property IS set in AD! Any help is appreciated.

EDIT 2: Here's the code for the custom principal extension:

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalExtension : UserPrincipal
{
    public UserPrincipalExtension(PrincipalContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public UserPrincipalExtension(PrincipalContext context, string samAccountName, string password, bool enabled)
        : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
    {
    }

    public static new UserPrincipalExtension FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType type, string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalExtension)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalExtension), type, identityValue);
    }

    PersonSearchFilter searchFilter;
    new public PersonSearchFilter AdvancedSearchFilter
    {
        get
        {
            if (searchFilter == null)
                searchFilter = new PersonSearchFilter(this);

            return searchFilter;
        }
    }

    [DirectoryProperty("employeeNumber")]
    public string EmployeeNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("employeeNumber").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("employeeNumber")[0];
        }
        set
        {
            ExtensionSet("employeeNumber", value);
        }
    }
}
```

And the custom search filter:

```
public class PersonSearchFilter : AdvancedFilters
{
    public PersonSearchFilter(Principal p)
        : base(p)
    {
    }

    public void SAMAccountName(string value, MatchType type)
    {
        this.AdvancedFilterSet("sAMAccountName", value, typeof(string), type);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
UserPrincipalExtension filter = new UserPrincipalExtension(context);
filter.AdvancedSearchFilter.SAMAccountName(UserPrincipal.Current.SamAccountName, MatchType.Equals);
PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(filter);

foreach (var result in search.FindAll())
{
    var q = (UserPrincipalExtension)result;
    var m = q.EmployeeNumber;
}
```

var m is always an empty string even though ALL AD entries have an employeeNumber.

EDIT: From active directory: [image: Active Directory]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am more confidant in how to fix your second method so I will answer that first. You need to specify the property in [`DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload(v=vs.110).aspx) when you do your search for the property to show up.

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);
search.Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass=user)(userprincipalname={0}))", sid); 
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeNumber");

var result = search.FindOne(); // FindOne();
if (result.Properties.Contains("employeeNumber"))
{
    //This should now work.
}
```

The reason it worked for `string.Format("(employeeNumber={0})", "11663");` is because any search clause you add automatically gets put in to the PropertiesToLoad collection.

---

For your first method, I think you need to call [`DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/913td91k(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass in the property to make it show up.

```
string sid = "";
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;
    //sid = user.SamAccountName;
    sid = user.UserPrincipalName;
    //sid = user.Sid.ToString();

    DirectoryEntry entry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

    entry.RefreshCache(new[] {"employeeNumber"});

    if (entry.Properties.Contains("employeeNumber"))
    {

    }
}
```

But I am not 100% sure if that will work or not.

---

For your custom user principal, I am not sure what is wrong. The only difference I see between what you are doing and what I have in a project that does it that I know works is you use `[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]` but I have `[DirectoryObjectClass("user")]`. Perhaps that is the issue

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("user")] //Maybe this will fix it???
public class UserPrincipalExtension : UserPrincipal
{
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the ideas but unfortunately they didn't work. The refresh cache was a good idea but the value was still an empty string. The other idea where you set the PropertiesToLoad was a great idea but it didn't work. I even took your reasoning a bit further and added employeeNumber to my query to try and force it to load, like this: search.Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass=user)(|(employeeNumber=99999)(userprincipalname={0})))", sid); <- you can see my bogus employeeNumber in my OR condition. No luck with either case.

Comment: Hmm. Are you 100% sure the employee that you are retrieving has a value in that property. I don't know but maybe it does not show up if no value is set. Take a look at [this old question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566887/how-to-set-a-binary-attribute-when-using-a-accountmanagement-extension-class), maybe it might give you a idea.

Comment: I just double checked and it's there. I queried for employee 11663 (myself) and I got back an object with 71 properties. EmployeeNumber was one of them. Queried again using my name, then by my sid, then by my userprincipalname and all 3 gave me the same object back, but minus the employee number property. I'll check out your old question, thanks.

Comment: I added an image from AD showing my employeeNumber.

Comment: Did `[DirectoryObjectClass("user")]` help at all? I am stumped, everything looks correct, I don't know what we are both missing.

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything... but I finally figured out the issue and it was a bonehead move on my part. My AD entry DOES have my employee number, however I'm running as an administrator which has a separate AD entry which does NOT have an entry. This was my problem all along. Thanks for your help!